# Equivalent definition of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

We define $\int f d \mu=\sup \{\mathcal{L}(f, P): P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition }\}$ where $\mathcal{L}(f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu\left(A_{i}\right) \cdot \inf _{A_{i}} f$ for an $\mathcal{S}$-partition $P=A_{1}, \ldots, A_{n}$.

I am looking to show that when $\mu(X)< \infty$ and $f$ is bounded then this definition is equivalent to using the upper sum $\mathcal{U}(f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu\left(A_{i}\right) \cdot \sup _{A_{i}} f$ with $\int f d \mu=\inf \{\mathcal{U}(f, P): P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition }\}$.

It was easy to prove that $\int f d \mu \leq \inf \{\mathcal{U}(f, P): P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition }\}$ by using the fact that $\mathcal{L}(f, P) \leq \mathcal{U}(f, P)$.

I am now left to prove $\int f d \mu \geq \inf \{\mathcal{U}(f, P): P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition }\}$.
I think this can be done by first proving it for when $f$ is simple and then generalizing but I am struggling. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\mathcal{U}(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{A_i}f\cdot \mu(A_i) = \int\psi_P$ where $\psi_P = \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{A_i}f\cdot \chi_{A_i}$ is a simple function.

Since $\psi_P \geqslant f$, we have $\inf \{\int\psi:\psi \geqslant f, \psi  \text{ simple} \} \leqslant \mathcal{U}(f,P)$ and, it follows that taking the infimum over all partitions $P$, we have $\inf \{\int\psi:\psi \geqslant f, \psi  \text{ simple} \} \leqslant \inf_P\mathcal{U}(f,P)$.

On the other hand, if $\psi = \sum_{j=1}^m b_j \chi_{B_j}$ is the canonical representation of a simple function $\psi \geqslant f$, then $b_j \geqslant  \sup_{B_j} f$ and $\int \psi =  \sum_{j=1}^m b_j \mu(B_j) \geqslant  \sum_{j=1}^m \sup_{B_j} f\cdot \mu(B_j) = \mathcal {U}(f,P_\psi)  $ for some partition $P_\psi$. This implies that $\inf \{\int\psi:\psi \geqslant f, \psi  \text{ simple} \}  \geqslant \inf_P \mathcal{U}(f,P).$

Hence, $\inf \{\int\psi:\psi \geqslant f, \psi  \text{ simple} \}  = \inf_P \mathcal{U}(f,P)$ and by a similar argument we also have $\sup \{\int\varphi:\varphi \leqslant f, \varphi  \text{ simple} \}  = \sup_P \mathcal{L}(f,P)$.

Since $f$ is bounded, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists, by the simple approximation lemma, simple functions $\varphi_\epsilon$ and $\psi_\epsilon$ such that $\varphi_\epsilon \leqslant f \leqslant \psi_\epsilon$ and $\psi_\epsilon - \varphi_\epsilon < \epsilon$.

Thus,

$$\int \varphi_\epsilon \leqslant \sup \{\int\varphi:\varphi \leqslant f, \varphi  \text{ simple} \}  = \sup_P \mathcal{L}(f,P) \\ \leqslant \inf_P \mathcal{U}(f,P) = \inf \{\int\psi:\psi \geqslant f, \psi  \text{ simple} \} \leqslant \int\psi_\epsilon,$$

and, for all $\epsilon > 0$,

$$0 \leqslant \inf_P \mathcal{U}(f,P) -\sup_P \mathcal{L}(f,P) \leqslant \int \psi_\epsilon - \int \varphi_\epsilon < \epsilon \mu(X)$$

Therefore,

$$\inf_P \mathcal{U}(f,P) = \sup_P \mathcal{L}(f,P) = \int f $$

Comment: @Richard I voted to reject your edits as I felt it would be better if you suggested the edit to RRL, via a comment here. (This means that no mistakes sneak under the radar, etc.)

Comment: @RRL I think it's not quite obvious that the definition in the last line equals the Lebesgue integral. In general it does not and it is vital that the space is of finite measure, or am I missing something? Furthermore there is a simple typo in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Richard. Yes  -- as $\mu(X) < \infty$ the difference between the upper and lower Lebesgue integrals must be $0$ as $\epsilon \mu(X)$ can be as close to $0$ as we like.  In general not, but OP states "I am looking to show that when $\mu(X) < \infty ...$".

Comment: @RRL Ah, never mind. I misunderstood the argument here. I thought you were simply referring to OPs definition of the Lebesgue integral above (prior to the "when $\mu(X)<\infty$"-part) which is incorrect. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the definition of the Lebesgue integral above won't work in general for negative (measurable) functions. Consider $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = -e^{-x^2}$. We have
$$ - \infty < \int_\mathbb{R} f d\lambda\,,$$
where $\int f d \lambda$ denotes the usual Lebesgue integral wrt. to the Lebesgue measure. (It's usualy defined by approximating measurable $f$ by simple functions. I'd suggest looking this up, since it is rather poorly explained in the book you mentioned.) On the other hand
$$
\sup \{\mathcal{L}(f, P) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\} = - \infty
$$
since $\mathcal{L}(f, P) = -\infty$ for all Partitions $P$.

Now, in order to use the definition 3.3 from Axler for $\textit{measurable non-negative}$ functions and show the result for measurable bounded $f \colon X \to [0, \infty]$ with $\mu(X) < \infty$, we first use linearity of the integral
$$
\int_X f d \mu = -\int_X (-f) d \mu = - \int_X \|f\|_\infty - \|f\|_\infty -f d\mu = - \int_X \|f\|_\infty -f d\mu + \|f\|_\infty \mu(X)\,,
$$
where $\|f\|_\infty$ denotes the sup norm. Since $\|f\|_\infty -f \geq 0$ we get by definition 3.3
$$
\int_X f d \mu = -\sup \{\mathcal{L}(\|f\|_\infty -f, P) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\}+ \|f\|_\infty \mu(X)\,.
$$
Observe that $\mathcal{L}(-f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu\left(A_{i}\right) \cdot \inf_{A_{i}} -f = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu\left(A_{i}\right) \cdot \sup_{A_{i}} f = -\, \mathcal{U}(f,P)$, hence
$$
\begin{align}
\int_X f d \mu &= - \sup \{-\, \mathcal{U}(f - \|f\|_\infty, P) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\}+ \|f\|_\infty \mu(X)\\
&=\inf \{\, \mathcal{U}(f- \|f\|_\infty, P) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\}+ \|f\|_\infty \mu(X)\,.\\
\end{align}
$$
Since $\sup_{A_{i}} (f- \|f\|_\infty) = \sup_{A_{i}} (f)- \|f\|_\infty$ in the defintion of $\mathcal{U}$ it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_X f d \mu &=\inf \{\, \mathcal{U}(f, P) - \|f\|_\infty \mu(X) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\}+ \|f\|_\infty \mu(X)\\
&=\inf \{\, \mathcal{U}(f, P) \mid P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition}\}\,.\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But, I know the conclusion  can fail if the condition that $\mu(X) < \infty$
is deleted (By Axler 3B, 4 (b)). Does this use the boundedness of $f$ and the fact that $\mu(X) < \infty$?